# RUN@cloud with specific JDK version

Tags: cloudbees

Is there a way we can specify the JDK version we are running on? Specifically, I have a java app (non webapp) that has an incompatibility with 1.6.0_35 and is erroring out for me on CloudBees. The package recommends 1.6.0_27, is that possible to specify at deployment time?

Comment: Are you sure your problem is a regression between 6u27 and 6u35? More likely the package maintainers recommended 6u27 simply because that was the latest update available at the time the package’s release notes were written.

Comment: They say it may be reporting the bug incorrectly. They said while they don't test on 6u35, they are investigating a potential bug at their end. Still good to know we can test on JDK 7 or 8 if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can specify the version with -Rjava_version on the command line - however, fine grained versions are not available (as we tend to update those) - it is more just 1.6, 1.7 or 1.8 lineage. I would recommend in that case -Rjava_version=1.7.